# MVC Bootstrap forms styling issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having a small issue with my bootstrap mvc form. the margin for the form-group doesn't seem to be working when i add my Razor. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

This is the form that doesn't take the styling properly

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home"))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="formGroupInputLarge1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Fullname", tabindex = 1 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="formGroupInputLarge2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Email Address", tabindex = 2 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="formGroupInputLarge3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Message", tabindex = 3 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Message)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Send Mail</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
}
```

But once i remove the Begin form it takes the correct styling

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="formGroupInputLarge1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Fullname", tabindex = 1 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="formGroupInputLarge2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Email Address", tabindex = 2 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="formGroupInputLarge3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Message", tabindex = 3 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Message)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Send Mail</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You are opening the form tag twice. Check in inspect element on your browser and you'll see it.

Comment: consider using [TwitterBootstrapMVC](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/). It might make your life easier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your creating nested forms (a form within a form) which is invalid and not supported. Change

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home"))
```

to

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class="form-horizontal", role="form" }))
```

and remove the second form element (and its closing tag)

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
```

As a side note, `<label for="formGroupInputLarge1" ...>` is not creating a correct `label` element since the `for` attribute has no relationship to any elements in your form. Instead use `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })` which will associate the label with the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

Remove second the form and use:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", 
            null, 
            FormMethod.Post, new { @class="form-horizontal" }))
{
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="col-md-8">
        <section id="loginForm">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Register as a new user", "Register")
                </p>
                @* Enable this once you have account confirmation enabled for password reset functionality
                    <p>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Forgot your password?", "ForgotPassword")
                    </p>*@
            }
        </section>
    </div>
```

Comment: Kindly explain OP what changes you made and why. Also please format it properly